# How do I create and select from an in memory table in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using Oracle's PL/SQL and would like to create an in memory table from which I can do selects.

Let's say I have a table with only 20 records with two columns:
special_id(int), out_date(date)

I want to collect those 20 records and stick them in memory so I don't have to do the same select 10,000 times and I want to be able to access those 20 records later.

I then have a loop running a different query and I'd like to do the equivalent of the following inside that loop:

```
select out_date 
from in_memory_table 
where in_memory_table.special_id = cursor.special_id (where cursor is from my current loop).
```

NOTE:  It makes no sense to loop through the in_mempry_table under ANY circumstance.  I just need to be able to access the data in that table.

I'm not including actual code here because I'd have to do a heck of a lot of work recoding so as to not give away company info.

Comment: What sort of table do you have?  If you have a nested table that is defined in SQL, you could `select out_date from table(local_collection_variable) where ...`.  Though it generally doesn't make a whole lot of sense to grab a bunch of data from SQL, load it into the PL/SQL VM, and then push it all back to the SQL VM.  I would guess that you'd be better off joining whatever table you use to populate the collection to the tables in your cursor definition.

Comment: A regular table will automatically be kept "in memory" (=buffer cache) if there is enough memory and the table is accessed often enough. You can even tell Oracle to pin the table's data to the buffer cache.

Comment: I can't use a regular table and I can't just access it via a join.  There's a lot going on here that makes this situation difficult.  I guess I'll just have to use a real scripting language instead of this abomination called PL/SQL.

Comment: @WickedJester Why can't you use a regular table or a join?  Are you worried about performance or simplifying the code?  If it's performance, it only takes about half a second to select all rows from a 20-row table 10,000 times.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a collection then? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS00501

Comment: I can assure you that PL/SQL is neither an abomination nor a scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, it might not have much sense to do so, but you could use some kind of [hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054773/pl-sql-datastructure-like-hashmap) to do the job for you. This uses associative arrays.

1) populate the hashmap at the beginning of your program

```
for x in (select out_date, special_id from input_table) loop
   my_hashmap(x.special_id) := x.out_date;
end loop;
```

2) instead of the select, you get the `out_date` when you need it with a

```
curr_out_date := my_hashmap(cursor.special_id);
```

3) enjoy, hope it helps make plsql friendlier to you